# Software to block internet for applications

Tags: windows-10, software-distribution, internet-connection

I am using mobile internet on my desktop computer. All the sudden I have found out there was like one giga mb lost for nothing and I assume it must be because of some other background applications. Is there any software where I could limit internet only for specific applications? Including blocking windows 10 for updates etc. Would appreciate your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows 10 you can set a WiFi connection as a metered connection. This will reduce usage, but you can't block apps from within Windows.

To set a connection as a metered connection first of all make sure you're connected to your hotspot and then open the Settings app, click Network & Internet, and make sure you're on the WiFi tab. 
Double check that you're connected to your hotspot otherwise this won't work.
Click "Advanced options" and then the second section of that page will tell you about metered connections and allow you to set your connection as metered.

As for individually block applications maybe this could help http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1841

I have no experience with it but it seems to do what you're after.